# How to properly implement a binder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

**Question was heavily edited during discussion with Oleg**

I'm trying to implement a binder for BigQuery in Spring Cloud Stream.

Full code of application is avaiable on [GitHub](https://github.com/Riduidel/bigquery-binder-example).

So far, I've written a `BigQueryBinderConfiguration` class which returns a `BigQueryBinder` the following way

```
@Configuration @EnableConfigurationProperties({ BigQueryConfiguration.class })
public class BigQueryBinderConfiguration {
    @Autowired BigQueryConfiguration configuration;

    @Bean
    BigQueryBinder bigQueryMessageChannelBinder(BigQueryConfiguration configuration, BigQueryProvisioningProvider provisioningProvider) {

        return new BigQueryBinder(configuration, provisioningProvider);
    }

    @Bean BigQueryProvisioningProvider provisioningProvider() {
        return new BigQueryProvisioningProvider(configuration);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when doing so, my other binders (Rabbit and Kafka) are no more recognized.

My testing protocol is as follows : I start my application and check in rabbitmq admin interface if my application registers as a consumer. This is not the case when this code is uncommented.

When debugging call to `bigQueryMessageChannelBinder(....)`, I observe the following things.

The `DefaultBinderFactory#getBinder(...)` method always return my BigQueryBinder instance. Debugging indicates that the call to [`this.context.getBeansOfType(Binder.class);`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/30a5785166566e6493e8fdf0bddaa1c94b136d31/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/DefaultBinderFactory.java#L110) returns a list that only contains my BigQueryBinder. I'm puzzled, because the other binders are in my classpath, and if I remove the factory method `BigQueryBinderConfiguration#bigQueryMessageChannelBinder(....)`, everything works fine.

I've discovered during debug that `DefaultBinderFactory` is the class that is used to associate a binder to a configuration name. I've also discovered that Binder implementations should not appear in [`Map<String, Binder> binders`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/30a5785166566e6493e8fdf0bddaa1c94b136d31/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/DefaultBinderFactory.java#L110). But unfortunatly, my Binder implementation appear in that list. i guess it has something to do with the bean nature. But how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is to first look at our new [TestChannelBinder.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/test). Basically it's a full blown binder backed by Spring Integration. In other words Spring Integration and it's channels play a role of a message broker the same was Rabbit, Kafka, GCP and other binders.
What's important about this binder is that it effectively demonstrates a bare minimum of what's required to implement a functioning binder.

Comment: I'm more and more thinkiing it' s not a question of binder, but rather a question of injection, since I rewrote my code based upon your TestChannelBinder, and I'm still stuck with only my binder ...

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. Is it possible to provide some reproducible sample on GitHub so we can take a look?

Comment: What I don't understand is where are you calling `getBeansOfType` from, given that each binder is created it it's own ApplicationContext to which you do not have access, and calling it on the ApplicationContext that runs the actual application always returns empty Map, no matter how many binders do you have. Anyway, example would help. You can also look at the existing binders. As much as I wan to help, i just don't have enough information

Comment: I have extracted a minimal working example at https://github.com/Riduidel/bigquery-binder-example and i will update both README and question according to your remarks

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and will post back if not this week then next

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversations in this issue [#1623](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1623) .

I want to consume/produce messages from/to Spring Cloud Stream channels to an internal event bus from Axon Framework.

Is the model in this photo correct?

[Application model with internal and external binder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8olh.jpg)

If it is correct,I think we should use the channels from Stream in custom binder by injecting beans or other methods.

In `TestChannelBinder` class the channels have been created in user code with calling constructor,How to use channels managed by Spring Cloud Stream in custom binder?

```
private SubscribableChannel provisionDestination(String name, boolean pubSub) {
        String destinationName = name + ".destination";
        SubscribableChannel destination = this.provisionedDestinations
                .get(destinationName);
        if (destination == null) {
            destination = pubSub ? new PublishSubscribeChannel() : new DirectChannel();
            ((AbstractMessageChannel) destination).setBeanName(destinationName);
            ((AbstractMessageChannel) destination).setComponentName(destinationName);
            this.provisionedDestinations.put(destinationName, destination);
        }
        return destination;
    }
```

Comment: Greetings, answers should contribute to the asked question. I would suggest asking a new question containing your problem instead and deleting this answer. Otherwise it will be hard for others to help you because your question can't be found. Here you can read how you can properly ask your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi.this discussion is related to this question.Thanks for the reminder.