# How to Autowire Binding interfaces?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

Based on the conversations in this issue [#1623](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1623) ,[Binder Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921839/how-to-properly-implement-a-binder/54952050#54952050) and [Spring Cloud Stream Refrence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_destination_bindings)

I want to inject Sink object,and subscribe a MessageHandler to input channel ,But it seems the object was not created correctly when Annotated ApplicationConfig is called.

```
 @Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureInboundEventMessageChannelAdapter(EventBus eventBus,Sink sink) {
        System.out.println("sink :" + sink.toString());
        System.out.println("sink input :" + sink.input().toString());
        System.out.println("Bus :" + eventBus.toString());
        InboundEventMessageChannelAdapter inboundEventMessageChannelAdapter = new InboundEventMessageChannelAdapter(eventBus);
        sink.input().subscribe(inboundEventMessageChannelAdapter);
    }
```

`InboundEventMessageChannelAdapter` is a `MessageHandler` in the above code.

Output :

```
sink :null
sink input :org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel@32940ff0
Bus :org.axonframework.eventhandling.SimpleEventBus@707a6ff6
2019-03-02 16:51:05.915  INFO 21 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

Comment: You are auto wiring Source, not Sink.

Comment: Hi.this is an example code from Spring Cloud Stream document.

Comment: But your language makes no sense `I want to inject Sink instance,and subscribe a MessageHandler to SubscribableChannel from Sink instance(sink.input()` and `@Autowire
private Source source` - show your complete application.

Comment: I am actually extremely curious to know why would anyone want to manually subscribe to a Binding (any binding for that matter) when the whole concept of Binding was created to ensure the subscription is done automatically and transparently to the end user.

Comment: I edited the question.I hope you understand what I mean.Thanks.

Comment: The repository : https://github.com/mehdichitforoosh/test-autowire-cloud-stream
@GaryRussell

Answer (score 0):

The best way to binding is the constructor way.
Autowired annotation some times instantiate the Object as null.
With constructor Dependency Injection it's possible to make properties final, so always has a value.

```
public SomeClass class {

    private final Source source;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass (Source source){
        this.source = source;
    }
    public void sayHello(String name){
        source
            .output()
           .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(name).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.The autowiring method(properties,setters,constructor) is not important here.toString() method on Sink object  returns null and input channel is filled with unknown channel name in Annotated(@Configuration) config class.